# Is it bad for a hard drive to download more than one file at the same time?

Tags: download

It was said frequent reads and writes to hard drives like BitTorrent would cause wear to the hard drive and probably shorten the service life of the hard drive.

How about simultaneously downloading more than one file at the same with browser or other file manager/downloader (not Bittorrent)? Let say for example downloading 6 to 8 files at the same time. The hard drive might have to write to 6 to 8 files at the same time, could this cause more serious wear to the hard drive?

Comment: Not from downloading. A modern hard drive can write at rates higher than 100MB/sec. Plus the operating system is supposed to cache (hold data in memory) reads and writes and queue them properly. I'd say Windows itself (+antivirus + updates) hits the drive way harder than anything you could do in downloads.

Comment: "It was said" is pretty vague. Do you have any links to specific claims made by specific sources? I've never heard anyone claim that and, frankly, it sounds really silly to me.

Comment: “it was said" for many years in my area. Everybody has heard about that....  I'm in Asia.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the output of resource monitor on my system right now:

[image]

I'm doing nearly *nothing* now. I've got *dozens* of files being read and written to. I have an AV scan munching through every single bit of a few files. 6-8 files being written to is *insignificant* compared to all the background housekeeping going on on the average system.

What you are probably, very indirectly referring to is the *duty cycle* of a hard drive. Your hard drive is constantly spinning, and reading and the heads move about and so on. Many consumer drives *arn't* designed to run 24/7 and try to save power/wear by going to sleep. Other drives—much like the proverbial [honey badger](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/honey-badger)—don’t care.

Hard drives these days are pretty reliable (especially if you pick carefully - backblaze has a [nice set of statistics](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/best-hard-drive/) worth looking at) , and you've got factors other than wear and tear that might kill them. Considering many companies use consumer drives for fairly heavy duty backups, your puny 6-8 downloads should be fine.

That said, hard drives die all the time - and not just due to wear or spectacular disk crashes. If its important, back it up. If its transient, meh, download it again. I tend to split up my work into different systems, but if I was torrenting off my main box, I'd stick a separate drive in, just so that its cleaner. It would also keep this mythical wear down on a system drive.

Answer (score 0):

What you're worried about is basically wear and tear on the access arm mechanism as it moves from one of the files being written to another. This is almost certainly not a concern. The access arm bearings, etc., are so overdesigned that they are just about the least likely things in a hard drive to fail. Once you exclude the occasional drive model or series with that were "broken as designed" (like the ones that attached the heads to the arms with a glue that failed at high temps, leaving the head to rattle around inside the HDA), then statistically, failures in the drive electronics are far more common than failures in the mechanics.

In sum: Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

> It was said frequent reads and writes to hard drives like BitTorrent
>   would cause wear to the hard drive and probably shorten the service
>   life of the hard drive.

This all sounds like some urban tech legend nonsense.

The problem with this theory is that even if you are *not downloading anything* or *copying anything t*o your hard drive *there is still a constant flow of data being read and written* to your drive from the system simply being turned on.

The OS is constantly writing log files and cache files and swapping out RAM and reading and etc… etc… etc…

That said, in the case of servers—which typically operate 24/7/365—the drives in those boxes need to be changed on a regular basis due to overall server life. Sure you can install server grade hard drives that last longer, but in my experience 2-3 years later that drive has to be changed. And it has nothing to do with how heavily the system is being used.

Past any of that if you are concerned about the service life of a disk, don’t worry about how many downloads you have but instead make sure your system has as much RAM installed as possible. Why? Easy: Most all modern operating systems cache data to RAM before writing to disk. This improves overall data throughput and—as a result—relieves some of the stressed caused by disk I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your comment:

> It was said frequent reads and writes to hard drives like BitTorrent would cause wear to the hard drive and probably shorten the service life of the hard drive.

you were referring to Solid State Drives rather than mechanical hard drives with spinning platters.
If the former, it is true that SSDs will fail after some amount of write activity, but most modern SSDs will take over a petabyte of write activity before showing signs of wear. (TechReport.com did a test of several SSDs. You can see their results [here](http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead).) If the latter, HDDs will take decades of read/write activity. Most have a MTBF rating (Mean Time Between Failure) of over 300,000 hours with some rated at over 1,000,000. And the heads don't actually make contact with the disk surface; they fly just microns over it. Years ago the heads used to park in an area of the disk called the landing zone (and suffered some wear from doing so), but most now park the heads completely off the disk.
And FWIW, BitTorrent or not has nothing to do with hard drive wear, as your download speed, even with BitTorrent, is still slower than the write speed of your HDD, unless you happen to have a T3 connection to the Internet and connect to sites that can transfer at that speed.